# Writing common formulas as expressions in R

Tags: r, expression, r-markdown

I'm doing a lecture on a new topic and will be including formulas. My goal is to make the entire presentation using `isoslides` in `RMardown`. I want to include the expressions as references for formulas in graphs. As these will be common expressions developed long ago, I was wondering if there is an R package or resource that has very common expressions (i.e. the Pythagorean theorem, etc.). My problem is not necessarily the formulas, but writing them as expressions in `R` that are correct. If there are no packages that have common expressions, could you please recommend some search phrases that I can use to start asking the right questions? Thanks.

```
plot(1:5, main = 'Example')
text(x = 2, y = 4, label = expression(sum(x[i], i==1, n)), cex = 5)
```

[image]

Comment: Why not write it in LaTeX, which you could do inline on RMarkdown?Do you absolutely need it in the plot?

Comment: I hadn't thought of that. Thanks!

Comment: I believe you can reference it and possibly make a table of formulas/figures. Would certainly be more powerful.

Comment: @Sada93, I'm not quite sure what you mean?

Comment: You know `help("plotmath")`?